# Is it possible to define a markdown cell in python?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I am creating a series of dashboards in python, which includes a series of graphs for specific institutions. I am running all of the graphs in a for-loop. I need to have a title page each time the institution changes. I have the markdown cell created, but I am wondering if there is a way to just call the markdown cell with a line of code, so I can just easily insert the content of the markdown cell into my for-loop. Is there a way to do something like this:

```
def title()
## Title Name
```

To then insert `title()` into my for-loop?

Answer (score 0):

I know you can use triple quotes to do a giant string, but I'm not sure if thats what you are looking for exactly. You could do something like this:

```
"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
"""
```

This can be set to a string if you wish, as well, which could then be converted to HTML via some librayr (I'm sure theres one out there) but it really depends on what you're aiming to do.